# Unable to compile file when a defconstant uses a function from the same file

Tags: common-lisp

This is `example.lisp`:

```lisp
(defun f (x)
  (* x 2))

(defconstant +n+ (f 1))
```

When I compile try to compile the file using `(compile-file "example.lisp")`, I get an error when compiling the constant: `The function COMMON-LISP-USER::F is undefined`. How can this be? I have already defined the function `f` before using it to define the constant. How do I define a constant whose value is the return value of a function?

I am using SBCL 2.0.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [`DEFCONSTANT`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_defcon.htm):

> [...] users must ensure that the initial-value can be evaluated at compile time (regardless of whether or not references to name appear in the file) and that it always evaluates to the same value.

But [`COMPILE-FILE`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw61/CLHS/Body/f_cmp_fi.htm) and [3.2.3 File Compilation](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw61/CLHS/Body/03_bc.htm) only require the `DEFUN` form to establish that `F` exists, not that is may be evaluated during compilation.

You need to `LOAD` the resulting file for the definition to be available in your environment (e.g. Slime compiles a file *and* loads the result). Likewise, when you evaluate forms one at a time in the REPL, the definition becomes available right away, as-if a small compile-load cycle was done.

You have two main options:

- wrap the `defun` in an `eval-when` form

  ```
    (eval-when (:compile-toplevel :load-toplevel :execute)
      (defun f (x) (* x 2)))
  ```
- put the two forms in distinct files, and have the second one depends in the system (in the defsystem sense) on the first one:

  ```
    (defsystem "foo"
      :components ((:file "define-f")
                   (:file "define-constant"))
      :serial t)
  ```

Comment: I noticed that I can avoid the problem by using `defvar` instead of `defconstant`. Is that a valid solution?

Comment: Yes, typically defconstant evaluates the initial-value during compilation so that the value can be injected directly later at the place it is being referenced; this is not the case with defvar, the code only references a variable (which you can dynamically bind too). That's why the initial-value can be evaluated later (at load-time/evaluation). Both approaches are thus not equivalent operationally but this is perhaps not important in your case